# How MariaDB does the character set conversion in an existing database?

Tags: mariadb

You can change the character set and collation from an existing database with

`ALTER DATABASE test CHARACTER SET='utf8'  COLLATE='utf8_bin';`

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-database/

and convert the tables with

`ALTER TABLE <tablename> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET <set> COLLATE <collation>;`

What exactly happens when you do this for a live database? Different character sets can take different amounts of disc space, so the disc usage can be different afterwards.

But **does the conversion itself require extra disc space** (or computation), and if so, how much?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly happens?

- Nothing happens to the existing data.
- No disk usage should change.
- *Future* `CREATE TABLEs` in that database will take on that charset and collation unless they explicitly set such.
- Ditto for *Future* `CREATEs` of Stored Routines.

That is, `ALTER DATABASE` mostly changes some defaults.

Yes, non-English text may change in size when you change the encoding ("character set").  But that change requires certain variants of `ALTER TABLE`

As for how many bytes are taken by individual characters:

- Accented characters (mostly) are 1 byte in Ascii and Latin*, but 2 bytes in utf8 or utf8mb4.
- If you want more specifics or different conversions, ask.

Caution:  "Conversion" is one thing; "fixing" is another:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases

Comment: Thank you! My bad, I forgot to add a mention about the table conversions with alter table. I edited the question - the main point is: How to make sure the db migration  goes ok when you already have data in the database and need to do the conversion.

Comment: @Arttu - Caution:  "Conversion" is one thing; "fixing" is another:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases